# Will new-style Coolermaster 4 in 3 modules fit an older Stacker 810 case?

Tags: conversion, case, drive-bay

Will a new style 4 in 3 module[image: coolermaster stack] ([STB-3T4-E3-GP](http://www.coolermaster.com/product.php?product_id=2542), a drive bay converter to convert 3x 5.25" bays into 4x 3.5" bays) fit an older style [image: stacker810][Stacker 810](http://www.google.co.uk/images?q=stacker+810&oe=utf-8) case - in particular does anyone have first-hand experience of this?

Comment: no direct experience, but the drive-bay converter you've linked to claims to be ATX compatible, so it should work.  i don't think ATX cases have changed all that much.

Comment: It should in theory but Coolermaster fairly conspicuously don't mention the 810 in the product docs.  810s have removable drive blanks in the front of the case that specifically fit into the fascia and the grill on the front of the STB module might possibly not fit.  I can't find any discussion in forums that says anything definitive either way about whether this will fit.  In the worst case I could just buy an 830.  They're not all that expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a super old question, but I thought this may help someone who may still be looking for the answer (like I was).  I just took the risk and bought one of the new cages.  I can confirm that the STB-3T4-E3-GP works just fine in the Stacker 810.  You just attach the black rails that came with the 810 to the sides of the drive cage and it slides in/locks into the tower just like the standard drive cage that the case shipped with.  It's also flush with the front bezel.